# Echo PHP variable inside PHP string

Tags: php, wordpress

I am pulling a value from a cookie and would like to echo it out inside a query post. I think I am doing something wrong with the single and double quotes. This is probably an easy fix for a PHP pro.

```
$showCntryID = $_COOKIE["altairUniCountry"];

$args = array(
'orderby' => 'title',
'order' => 'ASC',
'meta_query' => array(
    array  (
        'key' => 'country',
        'value'=>'show-'. echo $showCntryID; .'
    )
    )
);
query_posts( '$args' );
```

Answer (score 4):

You dont need echo, you are not outputting anything, just building an array:

```
'value'=>'show-'. $showCntryID,
```

Comment: world's fastest answer! 6 seconds. Thank you so much.

Comment: So echo is just when you need to have it write html on a page? Otherwise you can just write the variable name and it will "write" the value in its place?

Comment: Yes, this is just string concatenation. See the answer linked by @Rizier123